# How to add variables in a batch file

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm trying to get a list of numbers an letters like 11111111 and a letter. Letter si calculated with the number. Something like:

```
@echo off
set var=23
FOR /L %%H IN (40000000,1,49999999) DO (
set number = %%H+%var%
echo %number%A
)
pause
exit
```

I want to get (more or less)

```
400000023A
400000024A
400000025A
...
```

But without changing the FOR sentence... Is that possible?

Comment: It might help if you tell people the language you are using...

Answer (score 3):

To continue with what jeb stated, for your requested output, the code should be this:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=23
FOR /L %%H IN (40000000,1,49999999) DO (
  set /a number=%%H+!var!
  echo !number!A
)
endlocal
pause
exit
```

Comment: +1: The var does not need to be expanded when using SET /A. `set /a number=%%H+var`

Answer (score 2):

1. Avoid spaces with `set` statements
2. Use set /a if you want to calculate
   set /a number=%%H+var
3. Avoid percent expansion in a block (and also in a FOR block)
   Use delayed expansion instead (add a `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to your file)
   `echo !number!A`

Answer (score 1):

To use numbers in batch use

`set /a`

See `set /?` for all the info.

Answer (score 1):

jeb provided the hints needed to fix your code, and Jeff K actually implemented the fix.

However, since you are adding a constant to every value, it is simpler and more efficient to add the constant to the FOR /L start and end values.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set var=23

set /a "start=40000000+var, end=49999999+var"
for /l %%H in (%start%, 1, %end%) do echo %%HA
```

Answer (score 1):

There is, but with changing the FOR sentence.

You actually forgot the setlocal command right there.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

This command is needed in order to add variables.

Still don't get it?

Here's the code so that you will add variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cls
set var=17
echo %var%
pause
set /a var=%var%+7
echo %var%
pause
```

Try to find any errors and mistakes on my code. Then test it.

There you have it! Added variables!

Answer (score 0):

The best method is:

```
set /a counter+=1
```

so:

```
@echo off
set /a counter=
:Top
set /a counter+=1
echo 4000000%counter%A
GOTO Top
```

You can copy the code above.