# Batch script - Adding variable value to same variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to do something like this, but I can't make it to work.

```
for /F "tokens=1" %%a in (C:\Auxiliar4.txt) do (

 if !counter! EQU 3 (set /A failed=%%a)
 if !counter! EQU 9 (set /A completed=%%a)
 if !counter! EQU 6 (set /A total=%%a)

set /A counter+=1

)

set /A counter=0

set /A failedday=%failedday%+%failed%

if %total% NEQ 0 (set /A success=(%completed%*100)/%total%)
```

My problem is with these two lines:

```
set /A failedday=%failedday%+%failed%

if %total% NEQ 0 (set /A success=(%completed%*100)/%total%)
```

The first issue is with variable "failedday", I need to read numeric values from a txt file, assign them to those variables (failed, completed, total) and then assign the value of "failed" to "failedday". Then another FOR loop starts to read a different txt with same format, assign those numeric values to "failed", "completed", "total" again (losing the previous values), and add new value of "failed" to "failedday" keeping the previous addition (example, filedday=2 after first "for", after second should be failedday=2 + New"Failed"Value).

The second issue is with "IF" structure. I need to calculate the average of completed transactions taking values from "For" loop, only if "total" is not equal to 0 (to avoid divide by zero), but when I add this line my script crashes.

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks!!!

Comment: Is there `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the beginning of your batchfile?

Comment: Yes, there is. Sorry!

Comment: You would need to tell us what your problem actually is. Something that stands out is that you haven't apparently assigned a value to `failedday`. What makes you say that you are having trouble? What are the values of the variables, what are the values of the results, and what did you expect?

Comment: I edited my question to add more information. Thanks!!!

Comment: @user3728086 If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you have found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: None of this answers solve my question, that's why I still don't accept any solution @ErikGillespie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601764/how-to-add-variables-in-a-batch-file) that asks the same sort of thing.

Here's another reference for [doing arithmetic with DOS Batch files](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsArithmetic.php).

You need to enable delayed expansion to perform the arithmetic:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /A failed=0
set /A completed=0
set /A total=0

for /F "tokens=1" %%a in (C:\Temp\test.txt) do (
 if !counter! EQU 3 (set /A failed=%%a)
 if !counter! EQU 9 (set /A completed=%%a)
 if !counter! EQU 6 (set /A total=%%a)

 set /A counter+=1
)

echo Failed: %failed%
echo Completed: %completed%
echo Total: %total%

set /A counter=0

set /A failedday=failedday+failed

if total NEQ 0 (set /A success=completed*100/total)
echo Success: %success%
```

Comment: Delayed expansion is enabled, I forgot to paste that part. Your code doesn't work either. I read those questions, but this is a different situation: variables are outside the "For" loop. The second link is not what I'm looking for. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Gotcha. I tried my example out on a Windows computer and fixed the issues. I pre-declared and then forced failed/completed/total to be specific values within the `for` loop to verify the values were being retained after the loop falls through.

Comment: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is not needed for commands like `set /A failedday=failedday+failed` to work. It only enables the `!`-expansion syntax and has nothing to do with variable expansion in arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @AndriyM and what about `if !counter! ...`?

Comment: @Stephan: Um, what about it? It is not a `set /a` command. My comment was in response to this statement: `You need to enable delayed expansion to perform the arithmetic`.

Comment: ah - above there. Yes, correct. Sorry about confusion